# Connecting to a Docker container redis-stack from Google Colab

Tags: python, docker, redis, google-colaboratory

I have a Redis database running in a Docker container. I would like to access its data from a Google Colab notebook using Python.

On my local machine I can access the database on port 10001 with no problem (I have mapped the default 8379 to 10001). But using Colab I can't connect to it.

It says : "Error 111 connecting to 127.0.0.1:10001. Connection refused."

In my Colab Notebook I have installed Redis:

```
!pip install redis
```

Then I have created a connection :

```
import redis
client = redis.Redis(host = 'localhost', port=10001)
  
client.ping()
```

But it is not working. So I have changed localhost to 127.0.0.1:

```
import redis
client = redis.Redis(host = '127.0.0.1', port=10001)
  
client.ping()
```

But still ... connection refused. What can I try next?

Comment: Why `localhost`/`127.0.0.1`?

Comment: Isn't it the localhost IP address? While checking in terminal running the command ```docker inspect mycontainer```I the IP Address is 172.17.0.2. But still it is not working ...

Comment: But where is the container running? On the same machine as the Google Colab instance?

Comment: Yes on my laptop

Comment: But Google Colab is running in the cloud, on Google's servers. That is the `localhost` from the point of view of the notebook, it's not your laptop.

Comment: Right ... so is there any way to connect to a redis-stack running on docker on my local machine from google colab?

Comment: It's complicated. You'd need to know your public IP address, forward the port on your router to your laptop, with all the security risks associated with it, since the port will be accessible for everyone on the internet.

Comment: Maybe you could run Redis on Google Colab instead of your laptop: https://www.kdnuggets.com/2022/01/running-redis-google-colab.html